# Getting minutes from two DateTimes on different dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I am comparing two `DateTime`s to see if there is 10 or fewer minutes between them. If I do `DateTimeA - DateTimeB`, and `A` is on 4/1/13 and `B` is on 4/3/13 I won't get the desired results.

I am only worried about minutes. So `DateTimeA` takes place at 8:00 am and `DateTimeB` takes place at 12:20 pm, I would want the result to be 260 minutes.

Comment: Didn't you want to ignore dates and only consider times? What should be the result of `9:30 4/3/13` - `8:00 4/1/13`?

Comment: Originally - yes. Upon further examination, I found that the DateTimes were all on the same days. I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: What about `23:55` and `00:05` of the next day? Should that be 10 minutes too? As of now, you'd get 1430.

Comment: That's a great edge case, hadn't considered that. For the sake of helping others who might have issue I had originally noted, I will use your answer and put it in my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(DateTimeA - DateTimeB).TotalMinutes % 24*60
```

Get the total number of minutes [modulo](http://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo) the number of minutes in a day. That way you'll get rid of the different-day problem.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use `DateTime.TimeofDay()` To get the actual time values and then do arithmatic on them.

or use `DateTime.Minute` `DateTime.Hour` `DateTime.Second`. Here is a full explanation on `DateTime` objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score -1):

(A - B).TotalMinutes

A-B will yield a Timespan, for which the total minutes can then be produced.

Comment: This will yield a timespan in minutes between the two `datetime`s, not between the two `time`s. The OP is not interested in the timespan between days. Just hours/minutes - despite them falling on different days.